# Need help on DATE query in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server:

1. `EMP`
2. `On_Vacation` with colums `EmpId, LeaveType, StartingFrom, EndingTo,RejoiningDate`

The `On_Vacation` table stores the information of employees who are on leave.

[image]

I'm trying to query the table in such a way that my query has the following columns:

```
EmpId, 24-1-2016, 25-1-2016, 26-1-2016, 27-1-2016, 28-1-2016
```

The result query columns are the dates of this week. If `Employee` is not on leave on these dates, it should write `available`. Otherwise it should write the leave type.

I'm very new to this type of queries, kindly help me experts..

Comment: Create either a real or dynamic calendar table (one row per date) and then join it with your holiday table. After you have the results you can pivot it into different layout.

Comment: Thanks James. But, I need dates as columns?

Comment: That's what the pivot is for

Comment: SELECT OV.empid, IIF(ov.StartingDate<='2016-01-24' and ov.EndingDate>='2016-01-24',ov.VacationType,'Available') 
as [2016-01-24] from On_vacation ov. Im able to get the required result for a particular date but, I need the same thing for the week.

Comment: That's what the calendar table is for

Comment: Yes, I have created a table called "Date_Week". which has two columns (1. Date, 2. WeekNo). In this table I have stored all dates of 2016. But Im failing to write Pivot Query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101508/discussion-between-programmer2015-and-jamesz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the column name without dynamic sQL (which complicates matters).
Here's another suggestion:  what is you change your date table to includes the name of the day of the week, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DaysWeeks 
  (CalYear SMALLINT NOT NULL,
   WeekNumber TINYINT NOT NULL,
   CalDate DATE NOT NULL,
   DayOfWeekNumber TINYINT,
   DayOfWeekName VARCHAR(9)
   CONSTRAINT PK_DaysWeeks PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CalYear, WeekNumber, CalDate)
   )
```

with values like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DaysWeeks
        ( CalYear, WeekNumber, CalDate,DayOfWeekNumber,DayOfWeekName )
VALUES  ( 2016, 4, '01/24/2016',1,'Sunday'),
        ( 2016, 4, '01/25/2016',2,'Monday'),
        ( 2016, 4, '01/26/2016',3,'Tuesday'),
        ( 2016, 4, '01/27/2016',4,'Wednesday'),
        ( 2016, 4, '01/28/2016',5,'Thursday'),
        ( 2016, 4, '01/29/2016',6,'Friday'),
        ( 2016, 4, '01/30/2016',7,'Saturday')
```

Now, you can have a query which pivots based on the day of the week:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT EmpDays.Employee, EmpDays.CalDate, EmpDays.DoWName, ISNULL(v.Leave_Type,'Available') AS Available
FROM dbo.On_Vacation v
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT e.EmpID AS Employee, dw.CalDate AS CalDate, dw.DayOfWeekName AS DoWName
  FROM dbo.DaysWeeks dw,
      dbo.Employee e
      WHERE dw.CalYear = 2016 AND dw.WeekNumber = 4) AS EmpDays
ON
   v.EmpID = EmpDays.Employee
   AND v.StartingFrom <= empdays.CalDate 
   AND v.EndingTo >= empdays.CalDate
)
SELECT * FROM cte 
PIVOT (MAX(cte.Available) FOR DoWName IN (['Sunday'],['Monday'],['Tuesday'],['Wednesday'],['Thursday'],['Friday'],['Saturday'])
```

If your really need the actual dates in your columns, I would adjust this to use dynamic SQL.  But before doing that (which, IMHO, makes the code much harder to read and maintain, not that this is so straightforward), I'd ask how you were going to present the data and therefore whether that might be handled in the report or presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select e.empid,
       coalesce(max(case when '2016-01-24' between v.startdate and v.enddate 
                         then leave_type end),
                'available') as [2016-01-14],
       coalesce(max(case when '2016-01-25' between v.startdate and v.enddate 
                         then leave_type end),
                'available') as [2016-01-15],
       . . .
from emp e left join
     from vacation v
     on e.empid = v.empid
group by e.empid;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this works fine. But, how to use the dates dynamically as I have saved the dates in another table.TableName: "Dates and Weeks", which has two columns (1.Date and 2. WeekNo). Is there any way if I give only weekno, then the above query should run for all the dates of that week instead of writing each and every date?

Comment: @Programmer2015 . . .  Dynamic dates is a much harder question and not the question that you asked.  You could ask another question, but it is probably easier just to google "sql server dynamic pivot".